# Xcode 8.1 Still has Autolayout issue in Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios10, xcode-storyboard, ios-autolayout, xcode8

Storyboard getting issues in autolayouts, In Xcode 7 there was no issues in Autolayouts, when coming to Xcode 8.1 when i view the Storyboard in iPhone SE it looks like this ! [image: VC in iPhoneSE]
When i View the same VC in iPhone 7 it looks like this ! [image: VC in iPhone 7] with different layouts and with errors, but it works fine when i run in all sizes of simulators.

How to solve this in Storyboard?

Comment: What happens if...  Oops, sorry...  What to happen if you restate all those constrains from scratch with Xcode 8.1?

Comment: ofcourse it should break.I can see there are some aspect ratio constraints which are different for iphone 5,6,6p. When you run the app, OS will break some of the constraints that conflicts. I'm sure you will see autolayout message in the console when you run it for iphone 7.